# Restricting Spring Cloud Task instances

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-task

Will there be any such feature/support where only one instance of a task is allowed to execute at any given time and other instances of the same task will not be launched ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that?  If so, add a feature request on github here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/issues